# Equiareal mapping between surfaces

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I have a surface parametrized with $(u,v)$ with determinant of the first fundamenthal form $\Delta =EG-F^2=\cosh \sigma +v^2\kappa^2.$ Now I'm looking for reparametrization whose Jacobian $J$ will give $\overline{\Delta}=\Delta \cdot |J|^{-2}=1.$ I'm confused how to get square root in Jacobian (I have to get it because obviously my $|J|^{-2}$ needs to be $(\cosh \sigma +v^2\kappa^2)^{-1}.$ Any help?

Answer (score 1):

The problem (or at least ONE problem) is that there are too many possible solutions. If you find one new set of coordinates, then any rotated version of these, or any version of these followed by $(u, v) \mapsto (2u, v/2)$, etc., will work.

You can therefore narrow the search somewhat by saying "I'm just going to adjust $u$." You can say "Let's make $u' = f(u)$ (or, $u = f(u')$, which may be simpler -- see below), and see what conditions on $f$ are necessary for the determinant of the first fundamental form associated to $(u', v)$ to be one."

This should become a differential equation in $f$, which you may then be able to solve.

As an example, consider the usual lat-long parameterization of the unit sphere:
$$
(a, b) \mapsto (\sin a \cos b, \sin a \sin b, \cos a)
$$
This gives $\Delta = \sin a$, if I've got my sines and cosines right.

Now let's write
$$
a = f(a')
$$
Then 
$$
X(a', b) = (\sin f(a') \cos b, \sin f(a') \sin b, \cos f(a'))
$$
is our new parameterization, and 
\begin{align}
X_{a'} 
&= (\cos f(a') \cos b f'(a'), \cos f(a') \sin b f'(a'), -\sin f(a') f'(a')) \\
&= f'(a') (\cos f(a') \cos b, \cos f(a') \sin b, -\sin f(a')) \\
X_{b} &= (-\sin f(a') \sin b, \sin f(a') \cos b, 0)\\
X_a \cdot X_a &= f'(a')^2 \\
X_a \cdot X_b &= 0 \\
X_b \cdot X_b &= \sin^2 f(a')
\end{align}
so that the determinant is 
$$
\Delta = f'(a')^2 \sin^2 f(a')
$$
and you'd like this to be 1. That means that the function $f$ must satisfy 
$$
f'(t)^2 = 1/\sin^2 f(t).
$$ 
or (assuming $f'$ is positive everywhere, etc.)
$$
f'(t) = 1/\sin f(t).
$$ 
Writing this in a more familiar ODE kind of way, we have
$$
y' = 1/ \sin y \\
\sin y dy = dt \\
-\cos y = t + C\\
y = \arccos(-t + K)
$$

Now realizing that $y = \arccos(t + K)$ is also a solution (a different sign-choice a few lines up), and picking $K = 0$, we get
$$
f(a') = \arccos(a')
$$ 
so that
\begin{align}
X(a', b) 
&= (\sin f(a') \cos b, \sin f(a') \sin b, \cos f(a')) \\
&= (\sin \arccos(a') \cos b, \sin \arccos(a')) \sin b, \cos \arccos a') \\
&= (\sqrt(1-a'^2)\cos b, \sqrt(1-a'^2) \sin b, a')
\end{align}
which is an area-preserving parameterization of the sphere. It's more often written 
$$
X(h, \theta) = (\sqrt{1-h^2} \cos \theta, \sqrt{1-h^2} \sin \theta, h),
$$
which corresponds to taking a cylinder whose axis is aligned with $z$ and radially projecting each $z = const$ circular slice of that cylinder to the circular slice of the sphere at the same $z$-value.